# Mysql auto increment help

Tags: mysql

I have table with fields like id,title,no,url.

I want to auto increment id field

the table already has 1000 records in it with **already** some assigned ids

Now i want to auto increament the records that are **newly** inserted only .i **do not want** to auto increment the already present 1000 records .

Is there way i can do this???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY id integer (11) auto_increment;

Answer (score 1):

Just set column to autoincrement. It will increment only new ids, and will set the autoincrement to max(id) + 1. Even when the column is autoincrement, you can set a value, and you'll change the autoincrement counter.

Please note, you have to create index on id, in order to make it an auto-increment field.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, just add auto increment to the field that has the ids already. The ids must be unique. The next auto_increment will be on the highest id present in the table....Try to use phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Check the largest value of the id

```
SELECT MAX (ID) FROM TABLE
```

and make the starting index for this table from the next value (+1)